# Assigning the number of lines in a files.txt to the array length-java

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

The program reads from a file.txt and assigns the data in the file to an array element. 
Now I don't know how many lines the file will have, so I cant initialize the array size and I don't want to use arrayList.

Is there a way to count the number of line in the file and assign that number to the array size?

Example of data in the file:

```
    Item 2333 $283

    Item 2343 $363

    Item 2655 $243

    Item 2853 $223
```

After the counting the array size would be set to 4.

Please be kind, I'm a beginner.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you could read the whole file first to count the lines, create the array, then loop again reading in the data.

Comment: Or you could set the array to large arbitrary length fill it up with `nulls`.  If it is not big enough use `Array.copyOf`

Comment: Is this a correct way? this is just part of the code.                                      int arrayl = 0;
String [] items = new String[arrayl];;

 while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
    arrayl++; 
}

Comment: Looks close, why don't you try it.

Comment: _"...and I don't want to use `ArrayList`"_ That is pretty much the wrong attitude you have there. You just make your job a lot harder and your code a lot slower. Just make yourself "want to use `ArrayList`" and all your problems go away.

Comment: Yep I tested it and when I System.out.print(arrayl);. It shows 1234.One last thing, does this mean the elements are still 0 or will they contain 1234? Thanks

Comment: @icza Maybe it is a homework assignment

Comment: You don't want to use an ArrayList at all? would it be ok to use it at first and end up with an array?

Comment: the code you posted in your comment is not ok: you initialize the array with a size of 0... that will not change by just increasing arrayl

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are several options that you can consider.

Option 1 Resize the array every time you get an overflow

```
   private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 10;
   private static final int INCREMENT = 5;

   String[] lines = new String[INITIAL_SIZE];
   int amountOfLinesRead = 0;

   // loop until end of file
     // read line
     if(amountOfLinesRead == lines.length) {
       lines = resizeArray(lines);
     }
     lines[amountOfLinesRead++] = line;

   public String[] resizeArray(final String[] originalArray) {
     // create bigger array
     String[] newArray = new String[originalArray.length + INCREMENT];
     // copy array
     for(int amountOfLinesCopied = 0; amountOfLinesCopied < originalArrayString.length ; amountOfLinesCopied++) {
       newArray[amountOfLinesCopied] = originalArray[amountOfLinesCopied];
     }
     return newArray;
   }
```

Option 2. Go through the file twice, once for counting how many lines and once for processing the lines

```
   int amountOfLines;
   // read lines until end of file is reached
      amountOfLines ++;
   // create array
   String[] lines = new String[amountOfLines];
   // loop again
      // put lines in the array
```

Option 3. Add a header line to the file which contains some meta data, in this case the amount of lines (this is not uncommon to do)

```
// read first line of file
// get the amountOfRecords field from the line
String[] lines = new String[amountOfRecords]
int amountOfLinesInArray = 0;
// loop through file till end of file
   if(amountOfLinesInArray >= amountOfRecords) {
     // error! header information was corrupt!
   } else {
     lines[amountOfLinesInArray++] = line;
   }
```

Comment: I think you need to answer this question more fully.  How do you know you get an overflow?  How do you resize?

Comment: consider using `Arrays.copyOf`

Comment: I know, but as he is a beginner he should learn how it works behind the scenes. But when he reads this he should check the Arrays api out ofcourse :).

Answer (score 0):

**There you go:**
**it's pretty simple :**

```
File fout = new File("xxx.txt");    //File Name 

 if (!fout.isFile()) // IF CANNOT FIND FILE
  {
   OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find: xxx.txt - is not an existing file");  
   System.out.println("xxx.txt - Parameter is not an existing file");
   return;
  }

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fout),"UTF-8"));

  String line = null;

  int lineCount = 0;

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
  {
    if (line.length()>1) // checks if he line is full and/or not blank
    {
     line.trim();
     lineCount++;
    }
  }

  br.close();  //closing the BufferedReader 

String[] tempArray = new String[lineCount];  //declare an array with the line number of the file.
```

Hope this helps :)

**Dave.**

Answer (score 0):

My question is why do you use arrays in first place when you don't have a fixed length of data? Your file may today be only 5 lines long and tomorrow 30.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/mn/Desktop/"+ "test"));
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> fLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            fLines.add(line);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<fLines.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(fLines.get(i));
        }
```

I don't see any reason you have to use arrays for this type of work.